# Are there more mixed nudist baths like Friedrichsbad in Baden Baden in Europe?

Tags: europe, hot-springs, nudism

I know that the [Friedrichsbad](http://www.carasana.de/roemisch.html) in Baden Baden is a mixed naturist bath (I've been there), but I wonder if there are more mixed nudist baths, hot-springs, thermes or spas like this one.

Comment: Note that it is mixed [only](http://www.carasana.de/de/friedrichsbad/startseite/ihr-erster-besuch/) on Tue, Wed, Fri, Sun, holidays and Valentine's Day.

Answer (score 9):

The [Schwabenquellen](http://schwabenquellen.de) bath in Stuttgart, Germany is also a nudist bath, but they have one day a month when they require a bathing suit.

Other baths in Germany do it the other way around like the [Schenkenseebad](http://www.schenkenseebad.de) in Schwäbisch Hall (not too far from Stuttgart or Baden Baden). It has one day a month for people who like to swim in the nude.

In general in Germany most saunas in public baths are mixed and nudist.
A lot of these places have indoor or outdoor pools within the sauna area that are usually nudist only. But you have to check individual places.